# How to make a block scheme with arrows in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, arrows, block

I am new to LaTeX, I have searched in many forums, but can not find, how to depict block scheme like on the picture. Could you please give me hints or commands, which i can use in this case? And my LaTeX doesn't run tikzpicture package....
Thank you very much in advance.
[image: I wish to depict scheme like this]

Comment: The fact that you cannot use `tikz` (IMHO the best tool for the job) sounds a bit strange. Can you elaborate on your requirements/restrictions?

Comment: @Bordaigorl In fact you CAN use `TikZ`.

Comment: @Dox indeed, I was referring to the OP's sentence "And my LaTeX doesn't run tikzpicture package" which sounds odd

Comment: You also can use  `pstricks`, more specifically `\pst-node` and its `psmatrix` environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is that there *is* no `tikzpicture` package. The package is called `tikz`. It defines the environment `tikzpicture`. So you'd want `\usepackage{tikz}` and then `\begin{tikzpicture}... \end{tikzpicture}` in the document itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `TikZ`? No problem! `:-)`

Here's a solution using the built-in `picture` environment:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(120,120)
\put(10,80){\framebox(100,15){Economic indicators}}
\put(60,80){\vector(0,-1){12.5}}
\put(10,52.5){\framebox(100,15){Social mood}}
\put(60,52.5){\vector(0,-1){12.5}}
\put(10,25){\framebox(100,15){Electoral results}}
\qbezier(9.8,87.5)(-5,60)(9.8,32.5)
\qbezier(110.2,87.5)(125,60)(110.2,32.5)
\put(110.2,87.5){\vector(-1,2){0}}
\put(9.8,32.5){\vector(1,-2){0}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Finally runs! Thank you so much, Paul! Dunno how to give you vote on this website, but thank you really!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way with pstricks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(6,8)


\psframe[linewidth=2pt](0,0)(5,2)
\psframe[linewidth=2pt](0,3)(5,5)
\psframe[linewidth=2pt](0,6)(5,8)


\psline[linewidth=1pt]{<-}(2.5,2)(2.5,3)
\psline[linewidth=1pt]{<-}(2.5,5)(2.5,6)

\psarc[linewidth=1pt]{->}(2.5,4){3.905}{-50.194}{50.194}
\psarc[linewidth=1pt]{->}(2.5,4){3.905}{129.805}{230.193}

\rput[c](2.5,7){Economic indicators}
\rput[c](2.5,4){Social mood}
\rput[c](2.5,1){Electoral results}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pablos, thank you for hint, but i am trying to run your code and it shows me error 
Undefined control sequence \psframe[linewidth=2pt](0,0)(5,2)
Undefined control sequence \psframe[linewidth=2pt](0,3)(5,5)
Undefined control sequence \psline[linewidth=1pt]{<-}
Undefined control sequence \psline

Comment: You have to run LaTeX -> PS -> PDF. Does this help?

Comment: I don't have PS in LaTeX window... Sorry, I am really new to this program... Where can i find it? Or do i need to install it?

Comment: XeLaTeX->PDF will do just fine too